# FindHamiltonianPath quits kernel

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Wolfram Tech Support has confirmed a bug in FindHamiltonianPath that affects Mathematica 11.3.0 under Windows 10.  I reported it when the function would sometimes cause the kernel to quit.  The function usually works fine.

When weighted graph G causes the function to fail on my Windows machine, I simply run FindHamiltonianPath@G in MathematicaOnline to get an answer (or a friend runs it on his Mac). The offending weighted graphs seem perfectly normal (unfortunately, I cannot post the geolocation data used to build the graphs).

Has anyone encountered this problem under Windows and if so, did you find a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The context `SparseArray` contains a routine `` SparseArray`FindHamiltonianCycle `` that you might use as a workaround. I am not sure, maybe it is also used as backend for `FindHamiltonianCycle` and `FindHamiltonianPath`. (I belief that it's not.) Just give it a try.

`` SparseArray`FindHamiltonianCycle `` works on sparse matrices, so the `AdjacencyMatrix` of your graph has to be supplied. Since it only searches for cycles, we just add an artificial vertex that is connected to all other vertices and remove it later. This can be done by appending a row and a column of ones.

```
G = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

a = SparseArray[ConstantArray[1, {1, VertexCount[G]}]];
A = ArrayFlatten[{
    {AdjacencyMatrix[G], Transpose[a]},
    {a, 0}
    }];
path = SparseArray`FindHamiltonianCycle[A];
i = FirstPosition[path, VertexCount[G] + 1][[1]];
hpath = Join[path[[i + 1 ;;]], path[[1 ;; i - 1]]]

HighlightGraph[G, UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[hpath, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

The drawback of this method is that it is randomized, so you will usually get a different path when calling `` SparseArray`FindHamiltonianCycle `` again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Henrik.  Your idea gave me hope but alas, the problem persists when using FindHamiltonianPath@G (this finds a shortest Hamiltonian path -- SHP -- and not simply a path on the edge-weighted complete graph G).  I took your idea and created a SHP from the TSP tour returned by FindShortestTour@G.  Now FindShortestTour is causing the kernel to quit in some instances.  I'll bring this to Tech Support's attention.

Comment: Yes, you should report to support in any case. This is the only way we can hope for better implementations in the future!